# Default size of Blocking collection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

I wanted to know the default size of Blocking Collection. Somehow my program is not able to add elements in blocking collection.

Comment: The default bounded capacity is -1 which means "no default capacity", beyond being a `BlockingCollection<T>`, it shouldn't be blocking at all.

Comment: Okay, My problem is that I'm not able to add elements in blocking collection so I'm thinking like collection must be full. Hence the question...

Comment: Which means it isn't using the default size. So your question is two questions: 1) what is the default size and 2) why can't my program add elements to the collection. The answer to 1) is "no limit" and the answer to 2) is "the collection is full, hence it was constructed with a specific limit". Check the `.BoundedCapacity` property to learn which limit was placed on the collection.

Answer (score 2):

The default size in this code:

```
var collection = new BlockingCollection<int>();
```

is that it has no upper limit, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287116(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the BlockingCollection class **without an upper-bound**.

*(my emphasis)*

You can also learn about this upper limit through the [.BoundedCapacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287159(v=vs.110).aspx) property which in this case would return `-1`.

[Try an example on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eahwvu)

Obviously an unbounded blocking collection still has a limit in the number of elements you can add to it in that eventually either an underlying array or the surrounding memory becomes full, but it is not an artificial limit imposed by the class itself.

If you're observing that you cannot add elements to such a collection, it blocks as will be the case, then obviously it was not constructed in this way.

Instead it was constructed *with* a specific limit and you can still use the `.BoundedCapacity` property shown above to learn about this limit.

Answer (score 0):

[As read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), the default constructor builds a  blocking collection without a upper limit. So your problem lies somewhere else.